# Css body height enigma

Tags: css, layout

I've tried to replicate a layout seen in path : https://path.com/i/M2lzb

As you can see in the layout css :

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { min-height: 100%;position: relative; }
body { }
```

Somehow they manage to get a working 100% min-height like behavior on the `body` without fixing `html` height. I've tried to replicate that, but it only works if I set `html { height: 100% }`, when I do, it breaks the background when the layout needs scrolling (on small height it becomes truncated).

I've disabled javascript & it still works on path website so it looks like to be 100% css.

I've tried to replicate the behavior with no luck (I did copy/paste all path's css!).

http://jsfiddle.net/J9fgc/2/

How do they achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick in the site you linked:

```
.background {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `.background` `div`, the `body` has still a behavior like 100% min-height without explicit height set on `html`. So to me it does not come from this (neither from `.dimmer`).

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood your question. It seems body is symply wrapping around element .view-invites, which is set to height 100%. I think it may be related to these properties {display: table; height: 100%;}. Anyway, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Giving a 100% height to body will do the job.

```
body {height:100%;}
```

Simple as that.

But I am not sure what you are actually talking about, the semi-transparent white background or the background image of the beach. Anyway, if this is what you don't want, then please reply in the comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/J9fgc/3/